I need the mysql query to remove all the characters and number after first appearing of number reGEXP_REPLACE is not working in myqsql
I have the trade name which contain the number and special characters so i want to remove all the content after first appearing of numeric value



trade name
expected o/p




HUMULIN R, HUMULIN R PEN
HUMULIN R


DURAGESIC-100, DURAGESIC-12, DURAGESIC-25, DURAGESIC-50, DURAGESIC-75
DURAGESIC


URSO 250, URSO FORTE
URSO




SELECT 
    oe.id,
    oe.exclusivity_id,
    oe.exclusivity_date AS expiry_date,
    oe.nda_no,
    oe.prod_no,
    '' AS comment,
    oe.exclusivity_code,
    opr.inn_group_id,
    ig.description inn_name,
    opr.trade_name AS trade_name, 
FROM
    grid_file_ob_exclusivity oe
        JOIN
    grid_file_ob_product opr ON opr.id = oe.product_id
        JOIN
    grid_inn_group ig ON ig.id = opr.inn_group_id
WHERE
    oe.exclusivity_date IS NOT NULL
        AND oe.exclusivity_date != '0000-00-00'
        AND opr.inn_group_id <> 0
        AND oe.de_active = 'Y'
        AND oe.exclusivity_code NOT LIKE 'ODE%'

ORDER BY oe.prod_no ASC;




I have tried reGEXP_REPLACE and substring this are not working in mysql
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN INSTR(trade_name, '0') > 0 
        THEN SUBSTRING(trade_name, 1, INSTR(trade_name, '0')-1) 
        ELSE trade_name 
        END 
    AS result 
FROM grid_file_ob_exclusivity;

so i need the expected trade by removing the content after first appearance of number in mysql select query

We dont write your code for you, we help you fix code YOU have written. So to get you moving, show us the things you have tried

@ashwinit what is your mysql version ?

select version(); // 5.7.41-log

You said you tried "reGEXP_REPLACE", but it was not added until 8.0.4. Probably time to upgrade as 5.7 is no longer supported.

what can be solution for 5.7

there are no numbers in HUMULIN R, HUMULIN R PEN so the expected result is not matching with the logic you described

This feels clunky, but works:
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION my_substr( str VARCHAR(255) ) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
    DECLARE ret VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE c VARCHAR(1);

    IF str IS NULL THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSE
        SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
        myloop: WHILE i <= len DO 
            SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
            IF c REGEXP '[a-zA-Z ]' THEN 
                SET ret = CONCAT(ret, c);
                SET i = i + 1; 
            ELSE
                LEAVE myloop;
            END IF; 
        END WHILE;
    END IF;
    RETURN TRIM(ret);
END$$

DELIMITER ;

And then use it like:
SELECT trade_name, my_substr(trade_name) AS result
FROM grid_file_ob_exclusivity;

Outputs:



trade_name
result




HUMULIN R, HUMULIN R PEN
HUMULIN R


DURAGESIC-100, DURAGESIC-12, DURAGESIC-25, DURAGESIC-50, DURAGESIC-75
DURAGESIC


URSO 250, URSO FORTE
URSO



Here's a db<>fiddle.
